# What was the significance of the weapon locked in Alice's drawer?

Tags: resident-evil

I missed out on playing the Resident Evil computer games, but enjoyed the films. What was the significance of the weapon amnesia Alice (1st film) discovers in her bedroom drawer?

Was it a nod to the Resident Evil computer game in which (I imagine) she would have had to gather the combination some place in the game so she could access the weapon? Or was it just a throwaway scene in the movie?

Comment: just FYI: Alice doesn't exist in the computer games, she is entirely a creation of the movie.

Comment: TY @Michael Edenfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Alice wakes up she has no memory of her former life, nor is she aware that she is supposed to provide security for the secondary entrance to the Hive. As a security officer, she would have had ready access to the weapons drawer (containing the two Heckler & Koch MP5s) and known the code had she not been deliberately targeted with an amnesia-causing agent by the Red Queen.

From a movie-making perspective, the scene is a way of connecting the opening scenes to the false mansion and showing the audience that behind the humdrum facade, [another world awaits](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/resevil.html).

> ALICE stands before an ancient wooden dresser with three drawers. She
>   opens them one at a time.
>
> The first contains crisp starched linens.
>
> The second, neatly ironed women’s underwear. Very white, very
>   conservative.
>
> The third, **a pair of Uzis with laser sighting, under-slung with
>   miniature grenade launchers.**
>
> ALICE stares at the weaponry. The look on her face says it all. **Who
>   am I?**

[image: Weapons Drawer]

On top of all of that, the film owes a great deal to its computer game roots where keypads and code-hunts are a regular feature;

[image]

Comment: So, it's not a throwaway scene, but is reminiscent of the PC games of that era? Please edit and add that to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @MajorStackings - You're not wrong. I've added a couple of game shots.

Comment: God, you've both made me wish I still had my old PSX and the *RE* games. There's nothing quite like beating *RE2* with Tofu.